# "Dynamic" picture in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, pdf, animations

Is there a way in beamer to have some kind of dynamic picture that will change if the mouse is moved over it or if the button is clicked?

Comment: Related : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65096/how-to-make-a-diagram-composed-of-superimposed-layers-where-the-viewer-can-make

Comment: Very interesting link, but this kind of solution needs javascript programming :-( And should only solve my second case (button clicked)...

Comment: Unfortunately, Javascript is seemingly the only way to achieve satisfactory interaction. (even worse only with AcroRead)

Comment: you can simply use `\inlcudegraphics<1>{...}` what should be on overlay <1> and so on.

Comment: `animate` package?

Comment: @Herbert No, this will not solve my cases: this will only make a predetermined animation; the above suggestion fit better

Comment: @AlexG 'animate' package will not do the job, but I will try to understand how the command buttons are made

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a straightforward solution using a Widget Annotation (Push Button) according to the PDF specification. It displays different pictures depending on the current mouse position and its button state (out, roll-over, button-down).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newsavebox\imga
\newsavebox\imgb
\newsavebox\imgc
\sbox\imga{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\sbox\imgb{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
\sbox\imgc{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}
\edef\imgwd{\the\wd\imga}
\edef\imght{\the\ht\imga}

\immediate\pdfxform\imga
\edef\normalappearance{\the\pdflastxform\space 0 R}
\immediate\pdfxform\imgb
\edef\overappearance{\the\pdflastxform\space 0 R}
\immediate\pdfxform\imgc
\edef\downappearance{\the\pdflastxform\space 0 R}

\begin{document}

\hbox to \imgwd{\vbox to \imght{\vss%
  \pdfannot width \imgwd height \imght depth 0pt {
    /Subtype/Widget
    /F 4
    /FT/Btn/Ff 65536
    /T (my dynamic image) % Widget name; must be unique
    /H/P
    /AP <<
      /N \normalappearance
      /R \overappearance
      /D \downappearance
    >>
  }%
}\hss}

\end{document}
```

In case of multiple Widget annotations, the Widget's names, as specified by the `/T (...)` entry, must be uniqe.

[image]

Comment: How did you created the GIF above?

Comment: Recording with `ffmpeg`, Gif optimization with `gifsicle`.

Comment: For those who are interested, the method for producing the window recording is given [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2868).

Comment: @AlexG I'm in trouble with your code: it works nicely only for the first occurrence of a picture, not for the following ones... I've tried to replace the \Widget subtype by a \Link, but it does not work

Comment: @LionelMANSUY : The PDF created from the code example works properly only in Adobe Reader (as demonstrated by the animated screen recording).

Comment: @AlexG Have you tried to put 2 or 3 of different animated picture on a page? In acrobat, only the first one is shown, in the previewer of Texmaker or in Foxit reader, they are all shown, but inactive... I'm suspected the need to create a AcroForm to correctly use a `\FT\Btn`

Comment: @LionelMANSUY Adding an `/AcroForm` entry to the PDF catalog is not required here. Just make sure that the Widget's names, that is, the `/T (...)` entries in the Widget annotation dictionary, are unique per annotation.

Comment: @AlexG Thank you very much, you save my life :-) ! I've tried many things, but not this entry