# looking a way to create toggle region in PDF generated by pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I am looking a way to generate a toggle region in PDF compiled by pdflatex. Something like this implemented with javascript in html

http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/

I remember long time ago I saw a post online to implement this function but I can't find that post anymore.

Comment: you can search for `ocgx` from Paul Gaborit. The manual has a few nifty examples. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65096/how-to-make-a-diagram-composed-of-superimposed-layers-where-the-viewer-can-make

Comment: But collapsing won't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use PDF layers, i.e. [ocg](/questions/tagged/ocg). That's the *only* way you can emulate collapsing.

Comment: I doubt that collapsing works in addition to hide/display page content using ocgs. The reason is that the effect of changing the current transformation matrix within marked content (`BDC` ... `EMC`) is not local.

Comment: @AlexG: You would have to put the rest of the page/block for both case (collapsed/uncollapsed) on different layers. Ugly, but it _may_ work (I haven't tested this for pages, I know it works for blocks).

Comment: Ok, this may indeed be possible, but difficult in case of multiple vertically aligned collapsable blocks. Every possible combination of expanded and collapsed blocks would have to be prepared beforehand.