# Is it possible to embed a scrollable frame inside a PDF?

Tags: pdf, embedding, javascript

(This is an end-of-year crazy question)

Is it possible to embed a (scrollable) frame or a PDF inside a PDF? If so, how to do it in (pdf)LaTeX?

This is something pretty common in HTML (see for example http://www.echoecho.com/htmlframes01.htm). Here it is a *webpage* with PDF frames https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/iframe-pdf.html

Here it is a *fake* screenshot so you get the idea.

Portable and non-portable (e.g. only-Acrobat) answers are welcomed.
[image: fakeframe]

---

Example of a down arrow below a frame. The up arrow can be on top of the frame and the triangles point up.

[image: downarrow]

Comment: Related but not the same thing: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96260/1871

Comment: As far as I can see, the only "off the shelf" scrollable element would be a multiline text field. However, to make it scrollable, you can not make it read-only. Another possbility would be placing a button field, and make the  scrollable PDF the icon. You then add scrolling buttons and appropriate JavaScript code to change the position of the icon in the field (see button field properties in Acrobat).

Comment: The closest to your requirements that you can get is probably this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211010

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Vertical scrolling based on the `animate` package; definition of command `\smoothScroll` taken from an earlier [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211010) with slight modifications.

As an example document, we take `lppl.pdf` from `TEXMF/doc/latex/base/lppl.pdf`, the pages somewhat trimmed.

**Update**  with suggestions incorporated:

---

Start auto-scroll by clicking on the "widget", pause auto-scroll on mouse-down in the "widget" (and moving the mouse out, while keeping it pressed).

The buttons above and below the "widget" step through the document on mouse click.

[Shift]+click on the buttons rewinds to the top or jumps to the bottom of the document.

---

Adobe Reader required. Open on ↗[**ShareLaTeX**](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/590c85ea849899a670910480).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{MnSymbol} % \triangle, \triangledown
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{media9}   % \mediabutton
\usepackage{xsavebox} % \xsbox{<xsbox id>}{<content>} , \the<xsbox id>

%%%%%%% docToBox  %%%%%%%%
\newcommand\docToBox[3]{%
  % #1 <file name (PDF)>
  % #2 <left> <bot> <right> <top> % trim pages by given amounts (PS points)
  % #3 <boxnum>
  \pdfximage{#1}%  just for counting pages
  \multido{\i=1+1}{\pdflastximagepages}{%
    \global\setbox#3=\vbox{%
      \box#3%
      \hbox to \textwidth{\includegraphics[page=\i,trim=#2,clip,width=\textwidth]{#1}}%
    }%
  }%  
}
%%%%%%% /docToBox %%%%%%%%

%%%%%%% smoothScroll %%%%%
\newcommand\smoothScroll[5][]{%
  % [#1] autoplay, controls, ... (see: texdoc animate)
  % #2 <boxnum>
  % #3 <viewport height>
  % #4 <steps>
  % #5 <steps per sec> while playing; >25 doesn't make sense
  \edef\mywd{\the\wd#2}%
  \edef\myht{\the\ht#2}%
  \edef\mytht{\the\dimexpr\ht#2+\dp#2\relax}%
  \xsbox{XFormOfDoc}{\usebox{#2}}% distill box into re-usable PDF XObject
  \edef\portht{\the\dimexpr#3\relax}%
  \begin{animateinline}[#1,width=\mywd,height=\portht]{#5}%
    \multiframe{#4}{
      dRaiseLen=\the\dimexpr-\myht+\portht\relax+\the\dimexpr(\mytht-\portht)/#4\relax
    }{%
      \begin{minipage}[b][\portht][b]{\mywd}%
        \raisebox{\dRaiseLen}[0pt][0pt]{\theXFormOfDoc}%
      \end{minipage}%
    }%
  \end{animateinline}%
}
%%%%%%% /smoothScroll %%%%%

\begin{document}\Huge

\newbox\lipsumbox
%load the document with trims into save-box
\docToBox{lppl.pdf}{131 110 115 121}{\lipsumbox}
\edef\boxwidth{\the\wd\lipsumbox}% 

\noindent Before you consider using \LaTeX, read the fine-print:\\
\noindent\mediabutton[
  jsaction={
    if(event.shift){anim.lppl.pause();anim.lppl.frameNum=0;}
    else try{anim.lppl.frameNum--}catch(e){}
  }
]{\fboxsep=0pt\framebox[\boxwidth][c]{\tiny\strut$\triangle\triangle\triangle$}}
%the scrolling widget
\noindent{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\fbox{\smoothScroll[label=lppl]{\lipsumbox}{0.79\textheight}{512}{25}}}
\vskip -0.8\baselineskip
\noindent\mediabutton[
  jsaction={
    if(event.shift){anim.lppl.pause();anim.lppl.frameNum=anim.lppl.numFrames-1;}
    else try{anim.lppl.frameNum++}catch(e){}
  }
]{\fboxsep=0pt\framebox[\boxwidth][c]{\tiny\strut$\triangledown\triangledown\triangledown$}}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very cool, can the animate controls be used a scroll control?

Comment: They can already be used as such, e.g. "<" and ">" for stepping. A slider doesn't seem possible to implement, though.

Comment: Yes, I mean if the buttons can be arranged vertical and on the side. Or perhaps have a short elongated button below the frame `[        vvv        ]` and one on the top `[          ^^^          ]`. See my edit at end of the post for an example image.

Comment: By the way @AlexG, what and how made you an expert in this trade of Acrobat/PDF/MultiMedia/LaTeX hacks? If I can ask.

Comment: @alfC Oh, thanks. Reading the PDF spec over and over again, and a lot of trial-and-error.

Comment: Very nice, do I need a particular version of `animate` for this to work. I get this error:  `Undefined control sequence.
\\smoothScroll ...elax }\@anim@reset \@anim@xform `

Comment: Is it going to generate 500 frame, in other words, will the document become huge with all these frames?

Comment: @alfC : The current version on CTAN/TeX-Live will do (and also the current versions of `ocgx2` and `media9`). The animation method uses PDF Form XObjects. The complete document is stored once  into such a re-usable object (`\@anim@xform{...}`), which is repeated with a certain vertical offset (`\raisebox...`) for every frame. Of course, a bit code overhead is necessary for this.

Comment: Ok, I'll test it when my Fedora upgrades to the latest TeXLive.

Comment: Thank you, it works with `3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2016/dev)`. There is a small glitch that is that if I click inside the frame the automatic scrolling starts (which is nice), but it can't be stopped. I don't know how to fix it. For now I use the `nomouse` option to avoid the problem altogether. `  \begin{animateinline}[#1,nomouse,width=\mywd,height=\portht]{#5}%`

Comment: @alfC In order to pause it, press the mouse button over the frame and keep it pressed while moving the mouse pointer out (as written in the answer).

Comment: Ah, ok. I read the complete answer long time ago and forgot. It is a pity that there is not a better way to stop the scrolling/animation.

Comment: @alfC Although a bit un-orthodox, this way of pausing/resuming an animation by mouse-down/mouse-up was designed on purpose. Because one has better control over the playing state, while giving explanations during a lecture, for instance.  You can be sure that the animation freezes when your finger presses the button. With a conventional click (press-release) to both stop and resume an animation, you can never be sure whether you end up with a paused animation or with one that runs away, especially when clicking in rapid succession. (The same behaviour was also programmed into VPlayer.swf, btw.)