# javascript interactive plot context

Tags: context, javascript

I am trying to embed an interactive plot into a ConText presentation. I'm not entirely sure if this is possible. I am using javascript code from [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/). For this I need three java scripts, two of which are fairly long, so I figured I could try to read them in using the \input command (not sure if this works within \startJScode)

From there I make the chart and call the object "plot." If I wanted to draw this plot in html I would simply create a div container. How can I make container (field?) in context to draw the chart? Also how can I reference the "plot" object in the container/field?

Here is the way I have set up the JS code:

```
\setuppapersize[S6][S6]
\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]
\setuptolerance[verytolerant,stretch] 
\switchtobodyfont[modern,20pt]
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=color,backgroundcolor=white]
\usemodule[fields,abr-pseudocaps]

\starttext
\startJScode {EXAMPLE}
\input amchars.js
\input serial.js
AmCharts.makeChart("plot",{
  "type": "serial",
  "categoryField": "category",
  "categoryAxis": {
  "gridPosition": "start"
},
  "graphs": [
    {
      "title": "Graph title",
      "valueField": "column-1"
    }
],
  "valueAxes": [
    {
      "title": "Axis title"
    }
  ],
  "legend": {
    "useGraphSettings": true
  },
  "titles": [
    {
      "size": 15,
      "text": "Chart Title"
    }
  ],
  "dataProvider": [
     {
        "category": "category 1",
        "column-1": 8
      },
     {
         "category": "category 2",
         "column-1": 10
      },
   ]
});
\stopJScode


\stoptext
```

Comment: Welcom to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript engines in web browsers (at which amCharts target) are very different from those shipping with the few JavaScript supporting PDF viewers (A-Reader, Foxit, PDF-XChange; which else?).

The most important ingredient for interactivity is a drawing canvas which is not available in PDF related JS engines (whose functionality beyond core JavaScript, version 1.5 of ISO-16262, is defined by [Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/11/Acrobat11_HTMLHelp/JS_API_AcroJSPreface.88.1.html#1515775) ).

The canvas element is part of HTML5 but not of core JavaScript. Thus, it is not possible to get toolkits such as amCharts working in the PDF context.

Comment: Thanks @AlexG, not the answer I was hoping for but the one I expected. Hopefully in time these drawing canvas will be added so we can make presentation with interactive charts that can run without an internet connection.

Comment: @ChristineBraun: I principle, chart apps could also be created in Flash, using the Apache Flex SDK, and embedded with the `media9` LaTeX package. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98686 for example.

Comment: @ChristineBraun: See http://flex.apache.org/tourdeflex for demos of the various charts widgets available with the Flex SDK. Go to "Spark Framework Components"-->"Charts".