# Dynamic model in Beamer

Tags: beamer, pdftex, animations

I know that it is possible to animate content inside a Beamer (and generally a LaTeX document) using different package `movie9`, `animate`, etc. But I would like to include a dynamic model like this one :

[image: Dynamic model in LaTeX]

Look at the slider at the bottom : it updates the dynamic model just above it (following physics rules, on the right by the way, given to it but whatever).

I would like to know how the author did it. Could you give please me your ways of doing it (involving code or not).

Comment: only in acroread!

Comment: Meaning ?
I'm not talking of displaying it but to create it.

Comment: the javascript support is acrobat only, you probably want to look at Donald Story's work in this area starting from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acrotex

Comment: Have a look at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/sine-and-cosine-functions-animation/

Comment: Very similar, if not duplicate: [Does TikZ support interactive animation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98446). True interactivity is only possible with Flex/Flash embedded into the PDF using `media9` for instance.

Comment: It's not similar at all because there is no interactions that I found other than radio button not changing the model's behavior but rather printing/hiding already calculated plots.

Comment: Look at the [second answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98686). This one seems to be what you are after: a slider to interactively change model parameters. Inside PDF this is only possible with Flash.

Comment: Is there any other way to obtain this behavior ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a code for the rotating induction machine field, it can be helpful to understand how to include equations on animations.
You can use one sinusoidal equation to represent the vectors.
If you want the exact animation, you need the spring shape.
If think there is a `\draw` command for the spring shape, you just need to change the position of the circles and link the spring between them.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{\secname}{\subsecname}
    \begin{center}
        \newcounter{angle}
        \setcounter{angle}{0}
        \begin{animateinline}[loop, poster = first, controls]{30}
            \whiledo{\theangle<359}
            {
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{75}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{15}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{2}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\RR}{3}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\P}{\R*tan(\b)}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Q}{\R/cos(\b)}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\p}{\r/tan(\a)}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\q}{\r/sin(\a)}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rt}{sqrt(3)}

                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\sa}{sin(\theangle)}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ca}{cos(\theangle)}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\sb}{sin(\theangle + 120)}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cb}{cos(\theangle + 120)}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\sc}{sin(\theangle + 240)}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cc}{cos(\theangle + 240)}
                    % Definitions

                        \newcommand{\Cross}{$\mathbin{\tikz [x=1.4ex,y=1.4ex,line width=.2ex] \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) (0,1) -- (1,0);}$}
                    % Armature
                        \draw (0,0) circle (\RR);
                        \fill[color=gray!40] (0,0) circle (\RR);
                        \draw[line width=2mm, white] (0,0) circle (.75*\RR);
                    %
                        \draw [line width=.2ex,color=red]   (0,.9*\RR)          circle (.2) node[red]{\Cross};
                        \draw [line width=.2ex,color=red]   (0,-.9*\RR)         circle (.2);
                        \filldraw[very thick, color=white!50!red, inner color=red,outer color=white!50!red] (0,-.9*\RR) circle (.1);

                        \draw [line width=.2ex,color=blue]  (-\rt*.45*\RR,-.45*\RR) circle (.2) node[blue]{\Cross};
                        \draw [line width=.2ex,color=blue]  (\rt*.45*\RR,.45*\RR)   circle (.2);
                        \filldraw[very thick, color=white!50!blue, inner color=blue,outer color=white!50!blue] (\rt*.45*\RR,.45*\RR) circle (.1);

                        \draw [line width=.2ex,color=green] (\rt*.45*\RR,-.45*\RR)  circle (.2) node[green]{\Cross};
                        \draw [line width=.2ex,color=green] (-\rt*.45*\RR,.45*\RR)  circle (.2);
                        \filldraw[very thick, color=white!50!green, inner color=green,outer color=white!50!green] (-\rt*.45*\RR,.45*\RR) circle (.1);

                    \draw[ultra thick,black,->] (0,0) -- (-.45*\R*\sc-.45*\R*\sb+.9*\R*\sa,-\rt*.45*\R*\sb+\rt*.45*\R*\sc);
                    \draw[thick,red,->] (0,0) -- (.9*\R*\sa,0);
                    \draw[thick,green,->] (0,0) -- (-.45*\R*\sb,-\rt*.45*\R*\sb);
                    \draw[thick,blue,->] (0,0) -- (-.45*\R*\sc,\rt*.45*\R*\sc);

                \end{tikzpicture}
                \stepcounter{angle}
                \ifthenelse{\theangle<359}
                {
                \newframe
                }
            {
        \end{animateinline}
            }
            }
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: All the answers that everybody gave are not dynamic in the way that I showed you: control during presentation over a parameter influencing the model's behavior.