# Interactive geometry package

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, animations, draw

I am looking for a package that can produce some basic geometric figures and can be incorporated in a pdf file in such a manner that it is interactive with the reader. More specifically, I want to draw a triangle ABC with its inner circle. And I want the points A,B,C to be "free" i.e. that the reader of the pdf file can change the position of A,B,C (and that the inner circle moves accordingly).

Is that even possible? If yes, what is the best/simplest option?
Thank you a lot.

Comment: Welcome. You are possibly making a PDF document (which is for reading) to a website or a software (which can be customized).

Comment: No, at best, predefined animations based on JavaScript can be embedded into PDF. Real interactivity is only possible via a plugin, Flash Player specifically. It is a somewhat dated technology, but currently the only option. And it is limited to Acrobat Reader and Foxit perhaps. Here is an example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98686