# Connect .swf with media9

Tags: pdftex, media9, adobe, javascript, xml

I found out that it is possible to call external `javascript` *in an browser* with my interactive `.swf` document using the [ExternalInterface](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb1.html) provided by Adobe. That means, that with e. g. button clicks I can trigger `javascript` commands (yes, I am aware of the `media9` mediabuttons.) However, that doesn't seem to be possible in an LaTeX-generated `.pdf`, as one can only import the `.swf` document itself *without* the additional js-commands.

If that weren't the case, I could connect my `.swf` to `media9` and therefore to other interactive graphics as well.

Is there a workaround or another possibility to achieve this?

**EDIT:** Let's add an example: Connect the `hslider` from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98686/196234) example to media9.

**EDIT:** Extend that example:

This is the slider in `mxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                initialize="init();">

    <mx:Script><![CDATA[

        public function change():void {                
            flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("anim[’my_anim’].frameNum = 10","");
        }

        ]]></mx:Script>

    <mx:HSlider id="aSlider" width="100%"
                minimum="0.1" maximum="3" value="0.1"
                dataTipPlacement="top"
                snapInterval="0.01" tickInterval="0"
                labels="[a=0.1,3]"
                allowTrackClick="true"
                liveDragging="true"
                change="change();"/>
</mx:Application>
```

As you can see, it should, for the sake of simplicity, just set the `frameNum` of another animation `my_anim` (created with the `animation` package) to `10`. However I can include this .swf with media9 without any problems, but there is no response to sliding.

What I am doing is probably nonsense, but my intention should now be clear.

Comment: The players of the `media9` package are controlled in exactly the same way as you describe, that is, through methods exposed to JavaScript via the ExternalInterface. Bi-directional communication is possible. Can you post a specific example? Otherwise, your question is too broad.

Comment: It seems like you're exactly the right guy to answer this, see edit :D

Comment: The swf in the linked example doesn't use ExternalInterface and cannot be controlled from outside. But, `VPlayer.swf` from `media9` does. Its Flex source code is here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/players/VPlayer.mxml .

Comment: Yes, but how to include the js-part of the .swf? I mean, that's an additional file, right?

Comment: Well, SWF may contain ActionScript not JavaScript, as far as I know. JavaScript embedded in the host document (PDF, HTML) is executed by the host application (Acrobat Reader, a Web Browser) and can call ActionScript functions of the SWF that are exposed via ExternalInterface. In the opposite direction, the SWF can call JS functions embedded in the host document. Do you have a minimal demonstration example of HTML with embedded SWF and JS, that you want to convert to PDF?

Comment: Thanks for adding an example. I need some time for it. At first I will have to dig out the old Flex installation to build the SWF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example demonstrates SWF to PDF-JavaScript communication using Flash's [ExternalInterface](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb1.html). The embedded Flash app `slider.swf` is a simple slider that changes the animation object's `frameNum` property.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{animate,media9}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[label=my_anim,step]{1}
\multiframe{10}{i=0+1}{
  \fbox{\Huge\i}
}
\end{animateinline}

\includemedia[activate=pageopen,width=0.5\linewidth,height=12ex]{}{slider.swf}
\end{document}
```

The precompiled Flash app can be downloaded here: https://agrahn.gitlab.io/swf/slider.swf

Its source file `slider.mxml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
  <mx:Script><![CDATA[
    public function change():void {                
      flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("eval", "anim.my_anim.frameNum = "+String(int(aSlider.value)));
    }
  ]]></mx:Script>

  <mx:HSlider id="aSlider" width="100%"
    minimum="0" maximum="9" value="0"
    snapInterval="1" tickInterval="1"
    labels="[0,9]"
    allowTrackClick="true"
    liveDragging="true"
    change="change();"
  />
</mx:Application>
```

is compiled to SWF using Flex (flex.apache.org)

```
mxmlc -strict -warnings -compiler.as3 -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries -compiler.optimize -keep-generated-actionscript slider.mxml
```