# Including Geogebra with slider in Latex

Tags: beamer, animations, geogebra

I made a very simple animation in Geogebra that uses the slider to show the position of the objects at different times, and thought it would be really cool to include this in my Beamer presentation. I would like to know if that's even possible. I tried exporting it as PGF/Tikz, but no luck, as it does display the slider, but only as though I took a screenshot of it. In other words, it is embedded in the image and clicking it doesn't do anything. If this is not possible, could you suggest some other way to include such animation inside the latex document controlled by the slider?

Comment: I would recommend recording a video of the animation and embedding this in the presentation.

Comment: I could only think of an [animated GIF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/240243/47927) or an interactive PDF. However, I have the feeling that including an iinteractive PDF into a Beamer slide will pose a lot of difficulties. Furhtermore, it seems that you cannot export such an interactive PDF from Geogebra in the first place.

Comment: When Flash was still alive, such kind of interactivity could be added to PDF via SWF applets and the `media9` package. It needed Acrobat Reader for viewing. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98686 . Unfortunately, this possibility is no more.